# ASP.NET MVC how to insert other html element inside @HTML.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

Normally, i would write something like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Account")</li>
```

To generate this:

```
<a href="/Account">Dashboard</a>
```

What i want to know is whether it is possible to generate the following HTML

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
```

Without having to create my own custom TagBuilder class.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [UrlHelper.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to generate the url:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account")">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
</a>
```